# How to fix this error in SVM classifier RBF kernel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

I had written MATLAB function for RBF kernel in SVM classification but I am getting the following error:

```
Error using function myrbf.
```

This is what I tried:

```
Mdl_SVM_Rbf = fitcsvm(feat_training,label_train,'KernelFunction','myrbf','Standardize',true);

function G = myrbf(U,V)

           [n,d] = size(U);
           
           nms = sum(U'.^2);
           gamma = 0.016;
           sig = 1/sqrt(gamma);
           c = 0.18;
           G = exp(-((nms'*ones(1,n) -ones(n,1)*nms + 2*U*U')/(2*sig^2)));
           
end
```